# add attribute to input data-validation with jquery

Tags: jquery, typo3

I have a select field

```
<select data-validation="required" class="form-control error" id="femanager_field_usergroup" name="tx_femanager_pi1[user][usergroup][0]">
<option value="">Bitte wählen...</option> 
<option value="2">Mitglied</option>
<option value="5">Nicht-Mitglied</option>
```

and a

```
<div class="femanager_fieldset femanager_title form-group"> <label for="femanager_field_title" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> Mitgliedsnummer </label> 
<div class="col-sm-10"> <input data-validation="mustNotInclude(letter|special|space)" class="form-control" id="femanager_field_title" name="tx_femanager_pi1[user][title]" type="text"> </div>
</div>
```

Depending on the selected option I show or hide 
`.femanager_title`
with jquery

```
$(function () {
$(".femanager_title").hide();
$("#femanager_field_usergroup").change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();
    if(val === "2") {
        $(".femanager_title").slideDown( "slow" );
    }
    else {
        $(".femanager_title").slideUp( "slow" );
    }
  });
});
```

How can I add 'required' to 'data-validation' if `.femanager_title`
is shown?

I want to have

```
<input data-validation="required,mustNotInclude(letter|special|space)" class="form-control error" id="femanager_field_title" name="tx_femanager_pi1[user][title]" type="text">
```

Comment: What plugin or code are you using that reads `data-validation`? My bet is it has other ways to manage rules programmatically

Comment: I use the CMS TYPO3 with the plugin femanager. I try to stop the validation of the input if the input isn't shown.

Comment: I mean the jQuery plugin or code

Comment: I don't use any special Qjuery plugin. The plugin femanager has some JS for validation of course.

Comment: In my project i use jquery validation plugin with bootstrap if i can suggest it's a perfect plugin simply and you can do all you want, there are dependencing functions just for your problem

Comment: That's a nice plugin. Because the TYPO3 Extension 'femanager' has its own validation javasript I don't want to add anything more.